# When use ResreverseGeocodeLocation of CLGeocoder but the returned placemarks is nil and the kCLErrorDomain error =8

Tags: ios, mapkit

I want to get the location by the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and I used the following code

```
//newLocation is a CLLocationCoordinate2D object
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:
^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error){
CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
self.locationInput.text =placemark.subLocality;
self.locationInput.text =placemark.ISOcountryCode;
}];
```

but the returned placemarks is nil and the error description is kCLErrorDomain error =8

Comment: What is the value of newLocation?

Comment: the new location is `[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:32.392917 longitude:119.416108]`

Comment: Does Apple Maps have road data there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return values are documented here.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010237-CH2-SW2

Number 8 is "kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult", so I suspect you're searching for something with no results. I've read elsewhere that CLGeocoder only runs on a device (not the simulator) but I haven't verified it myself. If you are sure your search string should get results, try your code on a device.

Comment: thank you. you are right, there may be some thing wrong with the location.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my network, you know, I'm in China.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was using a VPN connected to a Thai server, trying to do a  reverseGeocodeLocation on a UK postcode. 
When I switched the VPN to a UK server it worked fine.